# 7z will not find archive using subprocess

Tags: python, 7zip

Struggling with this for literally two weeks.  I can't get this .zip to unpack.  I know that it is correct because I can make it work in a standard command line and it in shows everything that I know is in it.  Trying to unpack a zip and then rename and copy portions of that file to another folder.  Here is the basic setup:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['7z', 'e', 'site']
sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

After that import I try and unpack it using:

```
sp.communicate([cmd, 'r"C:\Users\boster\desktop\data1.zip"'])
```

now it gets past this point because it moves onto my if else section but it doesn't unpack it.  I know that it will run the following because it gets to the end and returns my else statement and then prompts me to run the data again.

```
if "sz + business_date" == name: 
    shutil.copy(sz%s) % business_date
    os.renames(sales.xls)
    shutil.copy(sc%s) % business_date
    os.renames(cosales.xls)
    shutil.copy(aj%s) % business_date
    os.renames(money.xls)
    shutil.copy(cc%s) % business_date
    os.renames(count.xls)
else:
    print "Repoll %s for %s" % (item, business_date)
    print "Once information is downloaded press enter."
    re_download = raw_input(" ")
    data_one()
```

I've left out some of the stuff like the business_date portions because it's returning that as a variable in the else so I know it's grabbing that information correctly.  I just have no idea why this won't unpack.  Please help.  If this isn't sufficient I'll upload the whole module if you'd like.

Comment: Why do you have quotes around `'r"C:\Users\boster\desktop\data1.zip"'`? That's not how you do a raw string. It should be just `r"C:\Users\boster\desktop\data1.zip"`. Also, I don't think `"sz + business_date"` does what you think it does.

Comment: I'd tried it without the '' around the whole raw string and it still wasn't working.  Now that I changed it back I realize that I'm not getting the archive not found error but it's still not unpacking. The "sz + business_date" is supposed to return a value, for today's date as an example, of sz07312013. Is this correct?  The whole point of that section is to verify that the files being unpacked are for the correct date.

Comment: No, `"sz + business_date"` gives you the string `sz + business_date`. You should drop the quotes. I don't mean to be patronizing, but it seems like you don't have that much experience with some of the basic aspects of Python. I'd suggest making good use of the interactive Python shell to test out individual snippets of code so you're confident they do what you think they're doing.

Comment: Thanks jjin, I don't have a ton of experience but that was just a stupid mistake.  I did sort that out last night, and I'm definitely trying to take this piece by piece and make the individual section work and then include it back into the larger app.  Thanks!

Comment: Still haven't been able to find an answer about why 7z won't extract anything from the file.  My script won't return any errors but it also won't do anything.  And per your advice jjlin I've pulled just the subprocess out and am running it alone so I can really nail down just the errors with the extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get this to work.  It wasn't unpacking on the subprocess.communicate and since call can't be used with PIPE I just dumped all the commands at the beggining and ended up with the following.

```
def extract_data_one():
    for item in sites:
        os.chdir(r"\\svr-dc\ftp site\%s\Daily" % item)
        subprocess.call(['7z', 'e', 'data1.zip', '*.*'])
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when using 7zip compressed file with subprocess, I solved my problem by another way. This is my code,

```
def zip_files_in_special_path(rom_path, rom_name):
    pre_cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(rom_path)
    cmd_str = r'C:\7-Zip\7z a -tzip -r '+rom_name+' *'

    try:
        status = os.system(cmd_str)
        if status<=1:
            return True
        else:
            raise RunCmdError('run 7z to zip files failed!')
    finally:
        os.chdir(pre_cwd)
```

hope to help you.